# How to get result for Advance Search in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating an Advance Search form in which 5 dropdown lists exist. When form method="post". When the form is submitted after selecting one or more dropdown values (user is free to select all 5 dropdown's values or select value of just 1 dropdown and press "Search" button) we have to get only those values that are selected by the user and compare that selected values with box data values with AND relation.

Box data is available in a multidimensional array. We have to compare user-selected values with box fields and display only those boxes in the result that are matched with all user's selected values (using AND relation between the condition).

I am creating 5 variables in which store the user-selected data values. Before assigning values to variables make sure that dropdown value is selected or not? if value is not selected then the empty string is assigned to that variable.

Now, first, we have to check that the variable is empty or not? if not then we have to compare that value with the box field in a foreach loop, if all selected values are found in one box then that box is printed in the body of if condition.

```php
<html><?php
   if (isset($_POST['AS_submit_btn'])) {

     if( isset($_POST['AS_box_type']) ){
         $box_type = $_POST['AS_box_type'];
     }else{
         $box_type = '';
     }

     if (  isset($_POST['AS_box_backing']) ) {
         $box_backing = $_POST['AS_box_backing'];
     }else{                              
         $box_backing = '';
     }

     if (  isset($_POST['AS_box_edge']) ) {              
         $box_edge = $_POST['AS_box_edge'];
     }else{
         $box_edge = '';
     }

     if (  isset($_POST['AS_box_shape']) ) {
         $box_shape = $_POST['AS_box_shape'];
     }else{
         $box_shape = '';
     }

     if (  isset($_POST['AS_box_origin']) ) {
         $box_origin = $_POST['AS_box_origin'];
     }else{
         $box_origin = '';
     }

     $all_boxes = get_boxes_data();

     foreach ($all_boxes as $id => $box) {

        if ( ($box_type != '' && $box_type == $box['type']) &&
             ($box_backing != '' && $box_backing == $box['backing']) &&
             ($box_edge != '' && $box_edge == $box['edge']) &&
             ($box_shape != '' && $box_shape == $box['shape']) &&
             ($box_origin != '' && $box_origin == $box['origin'])
            ) {?>

          <div class="box_db_container">

            <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="box_db_img_container">

               <img src="<?php echo $box['url']; ?>" align="middle">

            </div>

          <div class="box_title">

               <?php echo ucfirst($box['name']); ?>

          </div>

         </div><?php 
        }
      } 
   }?>
</html>
```

We have to make a combination of inner if-condition of all selected dropdown values. 1 value is selected or all 5 values are selected only that boxes are displayed their values are found in box values.

Comment: Without the rendered html it is really difficult to picture what you are asking. Consider including an example with expected result.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: A few mysteries in your question that need clarification: 1) what does `get_boxes_data()` do, exactly? 2) can you share the code where the `<select>` elements exist? 3) are those "boxes" at the top checkboxes, select options, or something else?

Comment: Clarification:
1) get_boxes_data() return a multidimensional array. 

$all_boxes = get_boxes_data();
$all_boxes[$box_id][array(in this array different box fields as saved)]

2) Select element code is a simple inline form code, in which there are 5 dropdown lists are displaying. This question is about the logic of advance search with respect to those 5 values (Code is lengthy for comment box). 

3) "boxes" are not checkboxes or any other object of HTML or CSS. The box is a thing just like a courier box, we already store information about that courier box in the database.

Comment: The Question:
How to get results for advance search?

Requirements from search;
1. User select options from dropdowns (5 dropdowns are on form, the user may select all or just 1) and submit the form.
2. First, we have to check which value is selected?
3. Then we want to compare selected values with Box field value (in foreach loop).
4. Use AND relation between selected values comparison.
5. Only that records are displayed as output that matches with all the user-selected values.